# C# Windows forms Calculator - Selecting textbox per click

Tags: c#, windows, forms, textbox

First of all, I'm german, 2. here is a screenshot of my calculator.. kinda weird but well i know xD

[image: My UI]

So, I'm looking for a Command:

I got 4 Textboxes, the 1st one(textBox1) for the 1. Number,
the 2. one(textBox2) for the Operator (+-*/),
the 3. one for the 2. Number 
and the 4. one for the Result

if i do:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  textBox1.SelectedText += "1";
  textBox3.SelectedText += "1";

 }
```

or

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
  textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + "1";
 }
```

the Number from the button I click on is shown in both textboxes now (1. and 3. one).
But I want that the Number of the button i clicked on is going to be in the Textbox i selected first.
So i first do select the textbox1 or textbox3 with simply clicking in it and then i click on a button(for example 1) and then the number 1 is going to be in the textbox i selected/clicked.

Comment: So you are German, means you are looking for German specific solution?

Comment: no, i just mean that my english is kinda special

Answer (score 1):

On the _Activate Event for both Textboxes, store which box was activated.  Then use that in the _Clicked event:

```
private TextBox currentTextBox;

 // Both textboxes can use this function
private void textbox_Activate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.currentTextBox = (TextBox) sender;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         currentTextBox.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a global variable **TextBox textBoxSelected** then in a event **textBox1_Click** and **textBox3_Click** set the variable. Later in **button3_Click** choose the textboxselected and add your logic. 
Try this:

```
TextBox textBoxSelected;
private void txtBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxSelected = textBox1;
}
private void txtBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxSelected = textBox3;
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxSelected.Text += "1";
}
```

Comment: how do i set up the global variable TextBox textBoxSelected?

Comment: i kinda feel bad for questions like that :c

Comment: Sorry for my english, the variable textBoxSelected is set in the method txtBox1_Click and txtBox3_Click see the code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I can't make much sense of your question, but I have noticed an issue in your logic.

C# will be adding them as strings, which results in concatenation.

Convert the values to integers first and it will add correctly.

```
textBox1.Text = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + 1;
```

As for you actual question, if you want to have a way of "remembering" what text box you clicked, add an event to the Click event to store the text box control that you have selected in a variable, and then use that in your logic.

Comment: im looking for a command that i can add the text of a button in on of the textboxes i selected

Comment: Are you wanting to set the text of a `TextBox` on the click of a `Button` ?

Comment: im kinda new to programming, so i dont have a clue how i can add an event :D only know the basics damnn

Comment: He *wants* concatenation... Just as when you press the "1" button on a calculator, a "1" is appended to the value being displayed.

Comment: @JamesCurran My bad, as I said I'm struggling to understand it. However, for the "equals" button, some conversion will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

So here are some recos:
1/ Naming convention: Use clear names that refer to the button function or the textbox content. Say for example: TextboxLeftOperand, ButtonN1, TextboxOperator, ...
2/ Use a new variable called SelectedTextbox 
var SelectedTextbox = new Textbox();
3/ Add to the click event of both textboxes an assignment of the SelectedTextbox.
For the left textbox:
SelectedTextbox = TextboxLeftOperand // textbox1 in your case
And for the right textbox
SelectedTextbox = TextboxRightOperand // textbox1 in your case
4. Now all you have is work with your new variable.